# Subject subscription not working on *ngIf component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a child component, which is loaded inside a parent component, but child is conditional and restricted loading with *ngIf condition

```
<app-child *ngIf="showChild"><app-child>
```

I have a common service, where there is a subject I`m subscribing in multiple places, but when child component is loaded later with showChild=true, the subscription for countryList$ is not working, because listener is attached later, any alternate solution for this??

Please help...

```
public countryList$ = new Subject();
```

Here is how I subscribe my countryList$

```
this.Service.countryList$.subscribe({
      next: (response: CountryList) => {
        this.countryList = response;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more code, including the part where you subscribe to `countryList$`.

Comment: Added my subscription code

Comment: And `this.Service.countryList$.subscribe({...)`  is placed in a ChildComponent?

Comment: Yes, I don`t want to change my subscription to the parent component and pass data from there, child component is used as child in multiple components, so every where I`ll have to make changes

Comment: Can you tell me if my solution worked? If so, it would be nice to mark it as "accepted answer" ;-).

Comment: I`m sorry for the delay, I`ve got busy with other work, I hope it will work, please give me some time, I`ll check and update as "accepted answer", thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `Subject` with `BehaviorSubject`. This way the last emitted value would always be cached and late subscribers will directly get the last emitted value. Please note: BehaviorSubject needs an initial value, which could be an empty array in your case.

The **Service** that provides the data:

```
export class DataService {
  public countryList$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() { }
}
```

**ChildComponent TS**:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public countryList: any[];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.countryList$.subscribe(countryList => {
      this.countryList = countryList;
    });
  }
}
```